# Como obter todos os dias de um mês usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como implementar um algoritmo que liste todos os dias de um determinado mês usando Javascript?

Pois possuo um combobox com os meses e preciso popular esse combo de dias de acordo com o mês selecionado.

Comment: Você já fez alguma coisa até o momento?

Comment: Que parte da tarefa está te trazendo dificuldade? Após extrair qual é o mês do `input`, tudo o que você precisa fazer é verificar quantos dias tem esse mês (dependendo do formato - em número, string, por extenso - pode ser mais fácil guardar esses valores num objeto) e gerar a lista que vai de `1` até aquele número de dias. A menos que você esteja se referindo a um ano específico, que pode ou não ser bissexto, etc. Por favor acrescente mais detalhes na pergunta esclarecendo esses pontos e mostrando o que já tentou fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementei algo bem rápido pra você ter uma ideia, a partir disso você pode popular seus select de Ano/Mês, a função recebe o mês e o ano. Nesse exemplo eu usei o mês de Dezembro de 2015.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("dias");
    var options = getDiasMes(12, 2015);
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

function getDiasMes(month, year) {
     month--;

     var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
     var days = [];
     while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        days.push(date.getDate());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
     }
     return days;
}
```

```html
Dia: <select id="dias"></select>
```

Comment: Valeu resolveu meu problema :D